# What's the easiest way to override the blue-ish tone of Android with the gray-ish one of KitKat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

In KitKat, there is been a (positive, in my opinion) shift in the design that has almost removed the blue color from the palette in favor of a light gray, favoring branding and customization.

**PROBLEM**

If you design your app on KitKat though, it's pretty sad to see your app when run on non-KitKat devices: that blue tone suddenly appears again.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I know how to set a layout with the selected state for a specific item (e.g., a Spinner, a ListView).
Looking for the answer to this question, I've learned about style-able attributes, that you can override in your Theme to widen those specific changes to a class of elements (e.g., all the Spinner(s), all the ListView(s))

**QUESTION**

However, what I am asking here is

What are all of the items I should override, in order to make the blue disappear from my app as much as possible?

Some item, I want to specify (since I didn't found anything for it) are

1. <del>The blue shadows that appear when you over-scroll a list</del> (solved with the EdgeEffectOverride library)
2. The menu selector on devices with the hard menu key and selector of the floating context menu.
3. The floating context menu selector.

*Additional notes*:
I am using the AppCompat library.

Comment: I believe overscroll and fadingedge were two components of a list view related to the glow effect and could be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [holo colours generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/), you can set your own colour theme (set it to default) and then use the kitkat styling, then set your applications theme to the new one...

Comment: that tools doesn't override the color of the menu items, when the menu is triggered from the menu button (almost all the non-Nexus devices). Also, this doesn't change the over-scroll shadows that appear when you scroll a list at its edges.

Comment: Just noted that this doesn't even change the buttons that appear at the bottom of a FragmentDialog.

Comment: Found a solution for the over scroll.

Comment: @domenicop If you have found a solution then you should post it as an answer to help others who have the same question in the future.

Comment: @Intrications yeah, sorry. I edited my question to mention it and upvoted even your other reply ;)

Answer (score 1):

The HoloAccent library could do this but unfortunately is currently API 14+ only so won't work for you with AppCompat.

https://github.com/negusoft/holoaccent

and see the screenshots at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.holoaccent.example

Comment: it's still a great resource for people coming to this question, and for me in the future I think. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The EdgeEffectOverride library can customize the overscroll colour and works back to API 10.

https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride